# java programming: logical operators and functions in android application

Tags: java, android, arrays, logical-operators

I have a functionality in my android application in which i can add phone contacts in layout dynamically and save the contact name and number in two arrays so it could be stored in shared preferences.

The conditions of this functionality is 
1. while adding a new contact it should be checked if we have the same contact in the list or not , if we have then we don't need to add it again.

2. user can just add maximum of five contacts in the list if he/she is adding more than five the first number of list or i should say the first index of array should be removed and the new one should be add at the end so it gets five numbers of max.

the problem i m facing here is while checking that is contactnumber already exist in list or not its function which is a return type and the call of **IsAvailableInContactList** to add contacts in **AddtoContactList** function crashing the application if i remove call to this function which is bellow its working properly but without checking for availability in list.

```
if(IsAvailableInContactList(paramString2).equals("true")){
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Contact already exist in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
          }
```

here are complete code for these:

```
public void AddtoContactList(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
     if(IsAvailableInContactList(paramString2).equals("true")){
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Contact already exist in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
      }

    if (this.contactlistcount >= 5) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     this.contactlistname[i] = this.contactlistname[(i + 1)];
        this.contactlistnum[i] = this.contactlistnum[(i + 1)];
          }
        this.contactlistcount = (-1 + this.contactlistcount);
          }

           this.contactlistname[this.contactlistcount] = paramString1;
           this.contactlistnum[this.contactlistcount] = paramString2;
           this.contactlistcount = (1 + this.contactlistcount);
          }


          public String IsAvailableInContactList(String paramString) {

          for (int i = 0; i < this.contactlistcount; i++) {
          if ((this.contactlistnum[i] != null) &&    (this.contactlistnum[i].equalsIgnoreCase(paramString))) {
                                j= "true";
                            }
                        }
                return j;
                }
```

I tried to used boolean return type in **IsAvailableInContactList** function but its creating problems and errors too.

I want to validate contacts for availability and then add them to array indexes
if it increases from maximum numbers one contact from beginning is removing and the new one is adding at the end but looks like something is wrong in the the syntax of checking availability function.

Hope i explained the problem properly.

any help would be much appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Piece of advice: **Use BOOL instead of String `true` and `false` values**. It's what bool is designed for lol, not the string :D

Comment: really? thanks alot for advice i didn't know this :D , I tried boolean too but its returning true even if number doesn't exist in array

Comment: Well, bool is the way to go but your logic was faulty somewhere... You're not gonna believe it, but it's hardly Java that did not work :/

Answer (score 0):

You can improve a lot of things in your code. I suggest some of the changes here -

1. You can use `ArrayList` instead of `primitive array`. This will help you in easily changing the contents as you have that requirement.
2. Them modify your `IsAvailableInContactList()` to return boolean true or false based on whether the `paramString` is present in your `contactlistnum`  or not -

   ```
   public boolean IsAvailableInContactList(String paramString) {

         if(contactlistnum.contains(paramString)){
               return true;
           }
       else{
            return false;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Finally change your `AddtoContactList()` -

   `public void AddtoContactList(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
        if(IsAvailableInContactList(paramString2)){
              Toast.makeText(mContext, "Contact already exist in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
         }

       if (contactlistnum.size() >= 5) {
            contactlistnum.remove(0); //Removes 1st item
            contactlistnum.add(4,paramString1); //Add the new item at the 5th index
       }
   }`

Hope these changes resolves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that really jumps out at me here is the way you are keeping two arrays to store data, when both depend on each other. If you have a contact number, you will always have a name to go with it, and vice-versa. So why not create a Contact class, like this:

```
class Contact {
    String name;
    String number;

    public Contact(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Contact))
            return false;

        Contact other = (Contact)o;
        return name.equals(other.name) && number.equals(other.number);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of managing two arrays, and running the same code on each array every time you do something, you only need one array.

Another point - you use the word 'List' a lot in the problem description, so why not store the contacts in a List, not an array? It has a lot of the functionality you are after.

```
// Wherever you declared your arrays 'contactlistname' and 'contactlistnum',
// do this instead:
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

// Now your code can be much shorter, easier to read and understand
public void addtoContactList(String name, String number) {
    if(IsAvailableInContactList(name)){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Contact already exist in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (contacts.size() >= 5)
        contacts.removeAt(0); // Remove the first contact in the list

    contacts.add(new Contact(name, number));
}


public boolean isAvailableInContactList(String name) {
    for (Contact contact : contacts)
        if (contact.getName().equals(name))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note that I also updated the `isAvailableInContactList` to use a boolean rather than a String.

Comment: thank you for your answer , actually the problem is not in defining array , it is in **isAvailableInContactList** function and i used boolean too but still when i m trying to add contacts when array is empty its crashing the application. while it should execute the codes after the second if condition in **addtoContactList**  in case if the array have numbers on it and i run the application **isAvailableInContactList** can check the availability but not adding new contacts or if its empty

Comment: When you say 'crashing', could you be a bit more specific? Please update your post with the exception that is thrown, then we might be able to help.